# psloggedon timeout

Tags: windows, pstools

I have a list of machine names from my network that I have put in a batchfile to run through the list and show me who is logged onto each.

```
psloggedon \\machineA
psloggedon \\machineB
psloggedon \\machineC
psloggedon \\machineD
psloggedon \\machineE
psloggedon \\machineF
...
```

Psloggedon works fine, however when it hits a machine that isnt actually on the network, it hangs for a good 30 - 60 seconds before moving onto the next machine...I was just wondering if there was any way to speed this up so that if it hits a machine that isnt on the network, it moves onto the next machine in the list much quicker.

I have read in other places that this could be possible by adding a ping -n loop into the command... but how?

Answer (score 1):

In your case it would be the right thing do use ping command.

Start.cmd

```
FOR /F %%x in (c:\temp\pclist.txt) do call ping_psloggedon.cmd %%x
```

ping_psloggedon.cmd

```
ping -n 1 -i 200 -w 130 %1
if errorlevel 1 goto exit
c:\temp\pstools\psloggedon.exe \\%1
:exit
```

pclist.txt

```
PCNAME1
PCNAME2
PCNAME3
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know a way to do that in Dos.
Put you can use Autoit to get a "clear" list. http://www.autoitscript.com

Install Autoit then you can use this script.
You have to use newest psloggedon.exe (1.34)

Save the script as "NAME.au3" (NAME what ever you want) file.

Example:

c:\NAME.au3
c:\pclist.txt
c:\pstools\psloggedon.exe

```
#include <Constants.au3>
Dim $line, $line2, $file, $icount, $reg, $reg2, $reg3
$file = FileOpen("pclist.txt", 0)
While 1
    $line = FileReadLine($file)
    If @error Then ExitLoop
    $reg3 = ""
    $reg2 = ""
    $reg = ""
    If Ping($line, 200) Then
        $reg = @ComSpec & ' /C "' & @ScriptDir & "\pstools\psloggedon.exe -l -x \\" & $line & '"'
        $reg = Run($reg, "", @SW_HIDE, $STDOUT_CHILD + $STDERR_CHILD)
        While 1
            $reg2 = StdoutRead($reg)
            If @error Then ExitLoop
            If $reg2 Then
                $reg3 &= $reg2
            EndIf
        WEnd
        If StringInStr($reg3, "Error") Then
            $reg = "Error"
        ElseIf StringInStr($reg3,"No one is logged") Then
                $reg = "No one is logged on locally."
        Else
                $reg = StringTrimLeft($reg3, StringInStr($reg3, Chr(13), "", 3))
                $reg = StringTrimLeft($reg, StringInStr($reg, "\"))
                $reg = StringTrimRight($reg, StringLen($reg) - StringInStr($reg, Chr(13)))
                $reg = StringStripWS($reg, 8)
        EndIf
        $icount += 1
        $line2 &= $icount & @TAB & $line & @TAB & $reg & @CRLF
    EndIf
    TrayTip("Psloggedon", $icount & " " & $line & " User: " & $reg, 10)
WEnd
FileClose($file)
ConsoleWrite($line2)
FileDelete("C:\output.txt")
FileWrite("C:\output.txt", $line2)
ShellExecute("C:\output.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add >> c:\output to c:\temp\pstools\psloggedon.exe \%1

```
ping -n 1 -i 200 -w 130 %1
if errorlevel 1 goto exit
c:\temp\pstools\psloggedon.exe \\%1 >> C:\output.txt
:exit
```

Now every time you start the start.cmd the results would be added to c:\output.txt

If you want you can add echo LoggedonUsers > c:\output.txt to start.cmd to get a clean output.txt at start.

```
echo LoggedonUsers > c:\output.txt
FOR /F %%x in (c:\temp\pclist.txt) do call ping_psloggedon.cmd %%x
```

What do you mean with "Would this also be ERRORLEVEL statement ?"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again mate :)

That works well too ! is it possible to output just the value of the machine name ? as opposed to all of the other text that i currently get in the output file..

So in output.txt currently it displays this...

Connecting to Registry of \LT013131...

Users logged on locally:
     19/11/2010 09:08:05        domain name\userid
Users logged on via resource shares:
     19/11/2010 11:44:17        domain name\userid

Is there anyway so that it just runs through the list and outputs just LT013131
?

So once the script completes I would just have a list of machine names ..

Thanks :)